# Python dictionary that maps strings to a set of strings?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I would like to be able to make a Python dictionary with strings as keys and sets of strings as the values. E.g.: `{ "crackers" : ["crunchy", "salty"] }` It must be a set, not a list.

However, when I try the following:

```
  word_dict = dict()
  word_dict["foo"] = set()
  word_dict["foo"] = word_dict["foo"].add("baz")                                    
  word_dict["foo"] = word_dict["foo"].add("bang")
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_input.py", line 56, in <module>
    test()
  File "process_input.py", line 51, in test
    word_dict["foo"] = word_dict["foo"].add("bang")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add'
```

If I do this:

```
  word_dict = dict()
  myset = set()
  myset.add("bar")
  word_dict["foo"] = myset
  myset.add("bang")
  word_dict["foo"] = myset

  for key, value in word_dict:                                                       
      print key,                                                                
      print value
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_input.py", line 61, in <module>
    test()
  File "process_input.py", line 58, in test
    for key, value in word_dict:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any tips on how to coerce Python into doing what I'd like? I'm an intermediate Python user (or so I thought, until I ran into this problem.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`set.add()` does not return a new `set`, it modifies the `set` it is called on. Use it this way:

```
word_dict = dict()
word_dict["foo"] = set()
word_dict["foo"].add("baz")                                    
word_dict["foo"].add("bang")
```

Also, if you use a `for` loop to iterate over a dict, you are iterating over the keys:

```
for key in word_dict:
   print key, word_dict[key]
```

Alternatively you could iterate over `word_dict.items()` or `word_dict.iteritems()`:

```
for key, value in word_dict.items():
   print key, value
```

Answer (score 31):

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_dict = defaultdict(set)
word_dict['banana'].add('yellow')
word_dict['banana'].add('brown')
word_dict['apple'].add('red')
word_dict['apple'].add('green')
for key,values in word_dict.iteritems():
    print "%s: %s" % (key, values)
```

Comment: +1 doesn't directly answer the question but can certainly make the OP's life easier here.

Comment: +1 didn't know that.. I had the same problem as the OP and this is very nice and IMO more readable than the accepted answer.

Comment: Python 3 renamed: `dict.iteritems()` to: `dict.items()`

Answer (score 7):

When you say `word_dict["foo"].add("baz")`, you are adding 'baz' to the set word_dict["foo"].

The function returns `None` -- updating the set is a side-effect. So

```
word_dict["foo"] = word_dict["foo"].add("baz")
```

ultimately sets `word_dict["foo"]` to `None`.

Just `word_dict["foo"].add("baz")` would be correct.

In the second scenario, when you say

```
for key, value in word_dict:
```

you run into an error because the correct syntax is

```
for key in word_dict:
```

to loop over just the keys in `word_dict`. In this situation, you want

```
for key,value in word_dict.iteritems():
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
word_dict = dict()
myset = set()
myset.add("bar")
word_dict["foo"] = myset
myset.add("bang")
word_dict["foo"] = myset

for key in word_dict:                                                       
    print key, word_dict[key]
```

It looks like standard dictionary iterator returns only `key` but not tuple.

Proof:

```
>>> d = { 'test': 1 }
>>> for k, v in d: print k, v
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> for k in d: print d[k]
... 
1
```

Comment: Alternately, `for key, value in word_dict.iteritems():` is a bit longer, but nicer on the access of `key` and `value` IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
word_dict["foo"] = word_dict["foo"].add("baz")
```

When you call `word_dict["foo"].add("baz")`, you're mutating the set that `word_dict["foo"]` refers to, and that operation returns `None`. So reading your statement right to left, you're adding "baz" to the set refered to by `word_dict["foo"]`, and then setting the result of that operation (that is, `None`) to `word_dict["foo"]`.

So, to make this work as you expect, just remove `word_dict["foo"] =` from your statement.

Dictionaries iterate on their keys by default, hence the ValueError you try this:

```
for key, value in word_dict:
```

What's happening here is that iterating on word_dict is returning a key only (say, "foo"), which you're then trying to unpack into the variables `key` & `value`. Unpacking "foo" gives you "f", "o", & "o", which is one value too many to fit into two variables, and hence your ValueError.

As others have stated, what you want is to iterate on the dictionary's key-value pairs, like so:

```
for key, value in word_dict.iteritems ():
```