# Appending list B with indices from enumerated list A

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, enumerate

I'm new to python. When I attempt to copy list strings and their indices, to a list variable created by a loop, I'm returned an empty list. However, printing the list before it's copied returns all the data I want.

This website gave me the idea to use a slice b=a[:] (http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list). It also doesn't work when I use this technique b = list(a) from the same website.

My goal is to create a series of lists with only one list for each unique character in a user input string. Each list would begin with the unique character followed by the indices of every occurrence of that character in the original user string.

```
for i, value in enumerate (xlist):
    exec "var%i=list()" %(i)
    exec "global var%i" %(i)

def enum():
    global character_count
    global xlist
    for i, value in enumerate (xlist):
        exec "global var%i" %(i) 
    for i, value in enumerate(xlist):
        if value=="%s" %str(xlist[character_count]):
            value=[value]
            value.append(i)
            print value 
            """<--This returns a full list"""
            exec "var%i=value[:]" %(i)
            exec "print var%i" %(i) 
            """<-- This returns an empty list"""

def enum2():
    global character_count
    global xlength
    while character_count<xlength:
        enum()
        character_count=character_count+1
        continue

enum2()
print var38


"""output ['?', 38]
   output []
   desired output ['?', 38]
   desired output ['?', 38]"""
```

I'm getting closer to what I want by updating a dictionary.
However, this returns only one index per unique character. I want all the indices.

Should use a set instead of a dictionary to append indices to a key/set? Is this possible with a dictionary?

```
"""Output
Input: Hello
{'h': 0, 'e': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 4}
Desired
{'h': 0, 'e': 1, 'l': [2, 3], 'o': 4}"""

string=raw_input("Input: ")
string_lower=string.lower()
string_list=list(string_lower)

string_dict = dict()
for i, j in enumerate(string_list):
    string_dict.update({j:i})
print string_dict
```

An answer has been found!

Comment: Whenever you think you want to create new variables in a loop, what you really need is one variable holding a list or dict. In this case, rather than `var0`, `var1`, `var2`, etc., you should be `append`ing things to a list.

Comment: You really should never have to use exec and/or eval, unless your doing something much lower level in my opinion. Dynamically creating global variables is a *terrible*, dangerous and inefficient idea, why don't you create a list or a dictionary of the objects you want and pass that around?

Comment: I'll just re-iterate this point. **DO NOT** use ``eval``, ``exec`` or ``global``. See other comments above.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will look into creating a dictionary of objects. My goal is to create a series of lists with only one list for each unique character in a user input string. Each list would begin with the unique character followed by the indexes of every occurrence of that character in the original user string.

Comment: I cannot stress this enough - **DO NOT** use `exec`, definitely don't use `eval`, and avoid using `global`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution came after modifying an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2285887/3761932) on ([Python dictionary that maps strings to a set of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285874/python-dictionary-that-maps-strings-to-a-set-of-strings))

Here's what I have

```
string=raw_input("Input: ")
string_lower=string.lower()
string_list=list(string_lower)

string_dict = dict()
for j in string_list:
    string_dict[j]=list()
for i, j in enumerate(string_list):
    string_dict[j].append(i)
print string_dict
```

Input: Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?

{'a': [2, 12, 24, 36], ' ': [5, 7, 15, 20, 23, 25, 34], 'c': [8], 'e': [14, 18, 19, 30], 'd': [35], "'": [32], 'i': [6], 'h': [1, 17], 'm': [10, 28, 29], 'l': [3, 4], 'o': [9, 22], 'p': [11], 's': [0, 26, 33], 'r': [13, 31], 'u': [27], 't': [16, 21], 'y': [37], '?': [38]}

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to the comment above, a simple way to implement a dictionary of such lists would be this:

```
string = 'efjseojfgiohgfiosjflk'
list_of_chars = dict()
for n in set(string):
    list_of_chars[n] = [n]*string.count(n)
```

The above is rather simple, human-readable, and allows for a stable way to access the newly created lists. It is at least better than using the evil that is `eval` and `exec`

Edit: I thought you wanted indices, not chars? I realized this afterwards, but apparently this is the 'correct answer'. You've sending mixed messages about what answer you require.

SuperEdit: OK, now you should place your correct answer as *the* correct answer. Don't give me credit where it's not deserved! :)